# How to use colorFilter with ngx-leaflet on Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-leaflet

How can i use a Leaflet plugin like [Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter](https://github.com/xtk93x/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter) with [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) on Angular 6 ?

I think my problem is in the import of the project because i want to use a function created by the `ColorFilter` plugin but this plugin is not a part of the Type Definition ( `index.d.ts` ) of `ngx-leaflet`. Am i right ? If yes, how can i fix it ? Is there a way to contribute a Type definition in the ColorFilter to be plug&play in the future and help other people like me ? Do you have some docs ?

### Here is my actual fail :

**app.module.ts**

Here i import `ngx-leaflet`

```
imports: [
    ...
    LeafletModule.forRoot()
],
```

**.angular-cli.json**

Here i import directly the JS file since i don't have a module in the `ColorFilter` plugin

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/leaflet.tilelayer.colorfilter/src/leaflet-tilelayer-colorfilter.min.js"
],
```

**my.component.ts**

```
import {circle, icon, latLng, marker, polygon, tileLayer} from 'leaflet';

...

ngOnInit() {
    const myFilter = [
      'grayscale:100%',
      'invert:100%',
    ];

    this.options = {
      layers: [
        tileLayer.colorFilter(
          'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          { maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...' },
          myFilter
        )
      ],
      zoom: 5,
      center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909)
};
```

**Error**

> error TS2339: Property 'colorFilter' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   tileLayer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make `lealfet.tilelayer.colorfilter` plugin to work on `ngx-leaflet`
you need to import it directly on component.ts as for some reason it is not possible via angular.json - Webpack does not seem to bundle the file allowing it to modify L namespace (it did not work in my case) and then although you should be able to call L.tileLayer.colorFilter directly in your component in my case it worked only using `(L.tileLayer as any).colorFilter`.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

import "node_modules/leaflet.tilelayer.colorfilter/src/leaflet-tilelayer-colorfilter.js"

...

defaultToDarkFilter = [
    'grayscale: 100%',
    'invert: 100%',
];

options = {
    layers: [
        (L.tileLayer as any).colorFilter('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
            maxZoom: 18, 
            attribution: '...' , 
            filter: this.defaultToDarkFilter
        }),
    ],
    zoom: 3,
    center: L.latLng(46.879966, -121.726909)
};
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3rlpo84y2m)

Comment: It's exactly what i needed! Thanks for the explanation and for the complete demo!

Answer (score -1):

From the ngx-leaflet module, it only exports directives. So you can attach the leaflet only into the DOM in template files. From the above code you are trying to access as component. https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/blob/master/src/leaflet/leaflet.module.ts

As per the GitHub Documentation  https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

**Template:**

```
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet 
     [leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
```

**Example leafletOptions object:**

```
options = {
    layers: [
        tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...' })
    ],
    zoom: 5,
    center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909)
};
```